# Response flow for the requests sent from Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, httpresponse, nginx-config

We have an application hosted in AWS. We have Nginx server (hosted in an ec-2 instance) in front of the application(micro services application). Every request will be hitting Nginx and then it forwards to the respective server hosting the corresponding service. Regarding the response, will it be sent to Internet directly from the server that processed the request or it will be sent back to Nginx and from there Nginx takes care.

I am new to Nginx. Just started exploring it. Any guidance regarding the response routing will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is acting as a reverse proxy in your configuration. The response goes back through Nginx. A server doesn't establish a new outgoing network connection to send an HTTP response, it uses the same network connection that was established by the incoming HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark for the response. Can there be any exceptional cases where response will not come back to Nginx or there is no way like that.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve or something? Or are you just trying to understand how networking works? Are you asking if there are cases where the response could be blocked, or cases where the response could bypass the proxy and go directly from the server to the client? There are no cases where the response could bypass the proxy, without somehow establishing a new network connection to the client, and that would be a feature you would have to build into your system somehow.

Comment: The main thing is to understand how Nginx works so that I can get complete picture on how our application is routing the response. In general, when an application server (ec2-instance) is behind a Network load balancer, the response will be sent to client directly without coming back to load balancer. Hence, want to understand the flow in case of Nginx. With your acknowledgement, I understand that in case of Nginx when some request is redirected to another server from Nginx the response will be routed back to Nginx and it will be taken care from there. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: "In general, when an application server (ec2-instance) is behind a Network load balancer, the response will be sent to client directly without coming back to load balancer." No that's not true. A load balancer is also a reverse proxy. The response passes back through the load balancer (through the established TCP connection).

Comment: Thank you very much Mark for the prompt responses. One query here: In our application,  the ec-2 instance hosting Nginx is in public subnet and the ec-2 instance hosting the application is in private subnet. In the post: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71203834/does-load-balancer-handle-request-from-server-to-another-server#,) it was mentioned that for an instance in private subnet traffic will be routed from NAT gateway -> Internet Gateway -> Public Internet. As Nginx is reverse proxy and our application server is in private subnet, how it can work in this case.

Comment: The NAT Gateway only comes into play when your server makes a new outgoing network request. Since the incoming HTTP request from the original client establishes a TCP connection, and that same TCP connection is used for the HTTP response, the response flows back up through the Nginx server, Load balancer, and any other reverse proxies, back up to the client that made the original request.

Comment: The NAT Gateway is needed for when your backend server in the private subnet tries to do something like download operating system update patches which requires it to be the one making the request to the Internet. In that scenario, the server would have to have a route to a NAT Gateway in order for its request to make it to the Internet.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark for all the help. In Nginx access logs, I see the response status and number of bytes sent. All doubts are cleared w.r.t response routing through Nginx and NAT gateway.